# usb disconnects for a little while

Tags: linux, usb

I am using Linux on a system that is constantly running. An USB Soundcard is connected to the system.

From time to time, on a random basis, sometimes in the middle of the night, the usb disconnects just to pop up again some seconds later.

```
Mär 18 03:52:41 test kernel: usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 35
 Mär 18 03:52:44 test kernel: usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 36 using xhci_hcd
 Mär 18 03:52:44 test kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=1024
 Mär 18 03:52:44 test kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
 Mär 18 03:52:44 test kernel: usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 Device
 Mär 18 03:52:44 test kernel: usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Generic
 Mär 18 03:52:44 test kernel: usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 20170726905959
```

The main problem is, that sometimes rhe device, after several reconnects, does not come up again until I reboot.

This happens not just on one system, but on like 100 of them.

**My questions are:**

1. How to get an extended USB log from Linuxs USB stack? I would like to find out if there is maybe something like a suspend mode involved
2. Is it possible, that the usb controller, after a while, is blocking the device until rebooting? Any other ideas why device is in the end not coming up again?

Comment: I was going to say your device must be buggy, but when I look in my journal I see several 'USB disconnect' messages. My guess is due to power management.

Comment: Exactly my first and second thought :) we are going to test the PM thingy within the next days. Thanks for your answer stark :)

Comment: Unfortunately, It wasn't the PM. We disabled the usbcore autosuspend but without any success. We also replaced the usb cable.

Comment: The path is port_event, which calls hub_port_connect_change, which calls hub_port_connect, which calls usb_disconnect. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/usb/core/hub.c#L5428